# Modify existing record rule odoo

Tags: xml, security, odoo, odoo-12, record-rules

I want to put  `<field name="perm_create" eval="False" />` to existing record rule .
so i added inherited it and added my addition .. but no effect:

```
<record id="hr_attendance.hr_attendance_rule_attendance_manager" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
</record>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because of `<data noupdate="1">`. `hr_attendance_rule_attendance_manager` is defined in `hr_attendance` with `noupdate=1`. So, you cannot change it normally.

As far as I know, there are 2 ways to solve this.

1. Remove `noupdate` via UI. Settings > Technical > External Identifiers > find your record (`hr_attendance.hr_attendance_rule_attendance_manager`). Then, uncheck "Non Updatable" field.
2. Remove `noupdate` with xml. I am referring to this question/answer. https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-can-i-update-a-record-stored-with-the-attribute-noupdate-1-78133

- Find record and remove `noupdate`.

```
<function name="write" model="ir.model.data">
    <!-- First we need to find the record...-->
    <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">
        <value eval="[('module', '=', 'purchase'), ('name', '=', 'purchase_order_comp_rule')]"/>
    </function>
    <!-- ...and temporarily set the noupdate field to False-->
    <value eval="{'noupdate': False}" />
</function>
```

- Apply the changes you want.

```
<!-- Get our main job done, i.e. modify the domain_force field of a record -->
<record id="purchase.purchase_order_comp_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="domain_force">[('company_id','=',user.company_id.id)]</field>
</record>
```

- (Optional) revert back to `noupdate` True.

```
<!-- (Optional) Time to clean our dirty hand, set the previously noupdate False to True again -->
<function name="write" model="ir.model.data">
    <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">
        <value eval="[('module', '=', 'purchase'), ('name', '=', 'purchase_order_comp_rule')]"/>
    </function>
    <value eval="{'noupdate': True}" />
</function>
```